# JS loop - how can i decrement from 1 to 100

Tags: javascript

Below is a loop that decrements. How can I rewrite this to count from `1` to `100`:

```
for (var i =100; i > 0; i--) {

    console.log(from 1 to 100);

}
```

Comment: You don't _decrement_ from 1 to 100. Do you mean increment?

Comment: Are you really asking how to **increment**, and couldn't you find this with a search, any search, anywhere?

Comment: i know it, now its write from 100 to 1, but i want revers it...

Comment: `for (var i=1; i<=100; i++) {...`

Comment: ehh i tryed....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rk05qf37/

Comment: dam it :) i have decrement and i want console loge it from 1 to 100 :)

Comment: I think you'll have to be clearer. You want to keep the loop you have, but log the *"opposite"* values? Why? Just change the loop? Otherwise, you just subtract `i` from the value you're iterating over, like in Nina's answer below.

Comment: Voting to close as either too unclear or duplicate

Comment: Is this really a question? I mean. Seriously.

Answer (score 7):

#### How to increment from 1 to 100

```js
for(var i =1;i<=100;i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```

#### How to decrement from 100 to 1

```js
for(var i =100;i>=1;i--){
  console.log(i);
}
```

**Only the last 50 lines are shown in the console in Stack Overflow**

Any previous output lines scroll off the top and are lost. So although the output may look incomplete, they were indeed all logged in the console.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the delta of `101`.

```js
for (var i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += (101 - i) + '\n'
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: I thought about it but it was strange to me

Comment: Why in the world would you start the loop reversely to print out 1 - 100??

Comment: @TrungHuynh, is it a question to me?

Comment: for @ŁukaszBuławski

Answer (score 1):

This will work but the snippet will only show 50-100.

```js
for(var i=1;i<=100;i++){
console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: From 1, not zero.